# Not possible to transfer the data back to the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am having issues trying to pass the data back to the `ViewController` (from `BarCodeScannerViewController` to `TableViewController`)

`SecondVC` (`BarCodeScannerViewController.swift`):

```
@objc func SendDataBack(_ button:UIBarButtonItem!) {
    if let presenter = self.presentingViewController as? TableViewController {
           presenter.BarCode = "Test"
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`FirstVC` (`TableViewController.swift`):

```
// The result is (BarCode - )
var BarCode: String = ""

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     print("BarCode - \(BarCode)")
}
```

Each time ViewWillAppear is running the value is not set, what could be causing this issue?

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: Have you ever heard about delegate pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the delegate pattern. I doubt in your code above that `self.presentingViewController` is actually set.

An example of using the delegate pattern for this:

```
// BarCodeScannerViewController.swift

protocol BarcodeScanningDelegate {
    func didScan(barcode: String)
}

class BarCodeScannerViewController: UIViewController {
    delegate: BarcodeScanningDelegate?

    @objc func SendDataBack(_ button:UIBarButtonItem!) {
        delegate?.didScan(barcode: "Test")
    }

}

// TableViewController

@IBAction func scanBarcode() {
    let vc = BarCodeScannerViewController()
    vc.delegate = self
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}

extension TableViewController: BarcodeScanningDelegate {
    func didScan(barcode: String) {
        print("[DEBUG] - Barcode scanned: \(barcode)")
    }
}
```